# "...target machine actively refused it..." exception in simple client-server app

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, tcplistener

While building simple client-server application I've got to a road block

while testing it's functionality in a loop-back
I always get

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:6001

this is the main server program it lays inside a `Task.Run(() => ...)`

```
internal void startListener ()
{
ListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(socketListener));
ListenerThread.Name = "Listener";
ListenerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
ListenerThread.Start();
ComThreadDictionary.Add(ListenerThread.Name, ListenerThread);
}

        public void socketListener()
        {
            _infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient.CreateNewTcpListenerANDstart();
            while (true)
            {
                _infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient.tcpSocket = await _infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient.peerListener.AcceptSocketAsync();
                byte[] StreamMessage = new byte[9632];

                Thread.Sleep(500);
                try
                {

                    MessageLength = _infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient.GetMessageLength(ref 
                    StreamMessage); 

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                    //"Remote host disconnected"
                }
                //Do stuff with message...
             }
         }
```

this is what nested inside this method `CreateNewTcpListenerANDstart()`

```
          CreateNewTcpListenerANDstart()
         {
          peerListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ComSettings.Port);
          peerListener.Start();
         }
```

peerlistener is declared inside like this : public TcpListener peerListener inside `_infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient`
nested method to collect message

```
    internal int GetMessageLength(ref byte[] StreamMessage)
    {
        int MessageLength;
        MessageLength = tcpSocket.Receive(StreamMessage, 0, StreamMessage.Length, 
        SocketFlags.None);
        return MessageLength;
    }
```

**EDIT** I've checked my client with netcat and it works so it is most surly the fault of the server

**EDIT2** the problem is with this function `_infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient()` , when I take all the component`(peerListenr)` out of it and Just put it the base(`socketListener()`) method all works  fine -> why is that ??

Comment: `peerListener` wraps the socket you start listening on, but you call `AcceptSocket()` on `_infrastructure_TcpServerAndClient`.

Comment: correct me if I wrong but I need the `AcceptSockt` to wait for incoming connection and handle them , meaning a stuck operation , isnt it ?

Comment: You're right, but you probably need to call `AcceptSocket()` on the `TcpListener` that you have started (`peerListener`), not on a different one.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I'm going to edit the code to fit mine , showing what differs between this one and mine , I've found what is the problem , but I dont know How to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was vary simple
in this function I'm manipulating to parameters locally which lead to `peerListener.Start()` to be started only locally , changing it to static did the Trick...

```
  CreateNewTcpListenerANDstart()
 {
  peerListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ComSettings.Port);
  peerListener.Start();
 }
```